# Why are requests to the Provisioning, Profiles, Reporting, Reporting Visualization, Admin Audit, Email Migration (v1), or Documents List API failing?

Tags: google-docs-api, google-provisioning-api, google-profiles-api, google-reporting-api, google-admin-audit-api

All of my calls to the following Google APIs have started failing:

- Provisioning
- Profiles
- Reporting
- Reporting Visualization
- Admin Audit
- Email Migration (v1)
- Documents List

Has something changed?

Comment: This post and a few of your others are under discussion [on Meta.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290897/is-seeding-broad-questions-and-self-answering-with-a-form-answer-to-create-a-faq)

Answer (score 4):

All the API listed were shut down as of April 20, 2015 as per the deprecation policies of the [Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/admin-api-terms) and [Documents List API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/terms).

Please see the following migration guides for more information on how to migrate:

- [Provisioning API to Admin SDK Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/migrate)
- [Profiles API to Admin SDK Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/migrate)
- [Reporting API to Admin SDK Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/migrate)
- [Admin Audit API to Admin SDK Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/migrate)
- [Email Migration API (v1) to Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/migrate-from-emapi)
- [Documents List API to Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/migration)

If the shutdown has impacted a business critical application, please [contact Google for Work Support](https://support.google.com/work/answer/142244).

Comment: There's no such thing as "Version v1 of the Google APIs".  This doesn't affect the large majority of Google APIs, just specific versions of specific APIs.

Comment: @EricDeFriez since make the answer better through editing. One thing that won't happen is having 6 different questions all on the same subject. I trust that Google knows the idea behind not wanting lots of duplication.

Comment: You've already presumed and decided different APIs being shut down are "all the same subject" even though they are distinct, against different services and have different developers.  I guess merely based on the fact they are from the same vendor and on the same date.  That seems unfortunate/misguided but it's your decision.  Since you made that decision I'd think you'd at least take responsibility and edit it well when marking as dupe--as it is now you've basically deleted real, usable data (e.g. can no longer find the APIs affected, links to all the various migration guides, etc).